# Extract all substrings meeting criteria using R regex

Tags: r, regex, string, substring

I have an extremely long string in R and would like to extract all substrings that match a certain criteria. The string may look something like this: `"some text some text some text [ID: 1234] some text some text [ID: 5678] some text some text [ID: 9999]."`

I have seen other questions posted like this that offer gsub as a solution but that seems to be in the scenario when only one substring needs to be extracted and not multiple.

What I would like to achieve as a result is a vector like this:

```
c("[ID: 1234]", "[ID: 5678]", "[ID: 9999]")
```

Comment: See `?stringr::str_extract_all`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
x = "some text some text some text [ID: 1234] some text some text [ID: 5678] some text some text [ID: 9999]."
unlist(stringr::str_extract_all(x, "\\[ID: \\d+\\]"))
# [1] "[ID: 1234]" "[ID: 5678]" "[ID: 9999]"
```

Answer (score 2):

Using base R, an option would be

```
regmatches(text, gregexpr(pattern, text))
```

which you can then `unlist()` if you want your output as an atomic vector.

Comment: Ok great that seems to be what I'm looking for thank you! I am not too savvy it terms of regular expressions. I think what I want to start out with is something like this: ".*\\[ID: ". What I am stuck on now is how to allow any number of numeric characters and then anchor the last "]" to the end of the string. Would you be able to assist with that?

Comment: @JordanHackett you can use the regex pattern in my answer with any regex method. `"\\[ID: \\d+\\]"`

Comment: Great that's awesome! Thanks @Gregor that works perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

```
inds = gregexpr("\\[ID: \\d+\\]", x)
lapply(inds, function(i){
    substring(x, i, i + attr(i, "match.length") - 1)
})
#[[1]]
#[1] "[ID: 1234]" "[ID: 5678]" "[ID: 9999]"
```